# MassTransit Azure publishing many messages

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm just wondering if anyone has ever had to **send/publish 1million+** messages to Azure using MassTransit.

It's currently a very slow process sending/publishing one message at a time (10 mins for about 25K messages). I can't see anyway of sending in batches of messages, but I may be missing something.

I do see Azure supports a SendBatch, which is limited to the overall message size of 256K, but we have many small messages which need to go out, and I'm wondering if anyone has extended MassTransit to support this functionality, or has some other advice on how to improve performance.

All advice greatly received.

Comment: I don't have experience with MassTransit or native batch sends. But I can confirm that sending a single message via ASB can take many milliseconds: never less than 10, up to 50 ms or even more. Even when calling ASB from a VM in the same region as the namespace. Which if you do the math on 25K messages, will add up to many minutes. 

ASB's performance is not too surprising given its design, but still - it's slow compared to say NServiceBus running on top of MSMQ - that never takes more than 1 ms.

Comment: Thanks Slava for your comments. I've similar experience with RabbitMQ, sending time is milliseconds, but moving to a cloud based architecture is where we're heading, so I'll need to look at some alternative approach to this. I can write the extension myself, I just need to figure out how to get at the Create message function in MassTransit (There is nothing obvious there yet, but I'l need to dig through the code), then serialise them and publish them in batches. Was hoping someone else may have gone to the trouble.